# Changing from Discrete Random Variable into Continuous Random Variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A random glass breaks at an exponentially distributed time, with mean 24 months. Probability that out of 500 glass, at most 210 breaks within a year? (Numerical answer, not just a formula)


First of all, using exponential distribution, the probability that a window breaks within a year is $e^{\frac{-1}{2}}$. I understand that we can simply find the CDF using binomial,

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{210} {500 \choose i}\left( e^{\frac{-1}{2}} \right)^{i}  \left({1-e^{\frac{-1}{2}}} \right)^{500-i}
$$

However, finding the numerical value for this is very impractical, and I figured the point of the exercise is to find the PDF in terms of a continuous random variable, that I can simply integrate? However, I can't figure out how to model the question with a continuous random variable.

Comment: It is possible to do this by integrating a PDF or by summing a PMF. To do it with a PDF, you need to find the probability distribution of the 210th break time, which is given by a certain gamma distribution. This is probably the harder way to do it. To do it with a PMF, you need to find the probability distribution of the number of breaks within a year, which you can do exactly with the binomial distribution as you say. With a computer you can evaluate this sum numerically with no approximation beyond the usual floating point approximations.

Comment: By hand you can treat this binomial as being approximately normal, which is justified because $500 \cdot \min \{ e^{-1/2},1-e^{-1/2} \}$ is rather large (say, bigger than 50). Of course even in this case if you want an answer in terms of an explicit decimal number, you'll need a computer or at least a calculator to evaluate the exponential and the normal CDF.

Answer (score 1):

What you are essentially looking for is the CDF of the binomial distribution.

A quick glance at the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) page (and the references therein) tell us that the CDF is defined by the regularized beta function which can be expressed as an integral as follows for $p=e^{-\frac{1}{2}}$, $n=500$ and $k=210$.

$$Pr(X \leq k) = (n-k) {n\choose{k}}\int\limits_0^{1-p} t^{n-k-1} (1-t)^k dt$$

You can evaluate the integral analytically.